# How should i handle LINQ internal exceptions?

Tags: c#, linq

The following query produces an exception of `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

```
        var results = products.SelectMany(x => x.features)
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.Category })
            .Select(x=> new features
            {
                 Category = x.Key.Category,
                 amount = x.Sum(x=>x.amount)
            });
```

while inspecting within the results

```
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Lookup`2.Create(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable`2.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator`2.ToArray()
   at System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1.get_Items()
```

That means that i cannot perform a null check

```
if(results == null)
{

}
```

or even

```
if(!results.Any())
{

}
```

How should i handle such "internal" exceptions? I wish to know if my query contains results or not.

Comment: I am curious as to why you believe that `results` might be `null`. Can you say why you believe that the reference produced by a query expression could be null? I am interested to learn why people believe false things about C# programming as it helps me understand how to design languages that are more easily understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to stack trace, you have null value in `Category` or in `amount`. So fix is simple:

```cs
var results = products.SelectMany(x => x.features)
    .Where(x => x.Category != null)
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Category })
    .Select(x=> new features
    {
            Category = x.Key.Category,
            amount = x.Sum(x=>x.amount ?? 0)
    });
```